# Is there a general way to calculate the similarity between product models or specifications?

Tags: search, nlp, e-commerce, search-engine

Product models and specifications always differ subtly.
For example:

`iphone6, iphone7sp
12mm*10mm*8mm, 12*8*8, (L)12mm*(W)8mm*(H)8mm
brand-410B-12, brand-411C-09, brand410B12`

So, in common E-commerce search, is there a general method to calculate the model or specification similarity?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a general method to calculate the model or specification similarity?

No.

This is a research topic sometimes referred to as "product matching", or more broadly "schema matching". It's a hard problem with no standard approach.

Finding out if two strings refer to the same thing is covered by **entity resolution**, but that's typically used for things like the names of people or organizations where a small change is more likely to be a typo or meaningless change than an important difference (Example: `Ulysses S. Grant` vs `Ulysses Grant`). Because a small change in a model number may or may not be important it's different problem. Specifications make things even more complicated.

Here are some papers you can look at for example approaches:

- [Synthesizing Products for Online Catalogs - Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Synthesizing-Products-for-Online-Catalogs-Nguyen-Fuxman/335d682595fd68983726b33fa7a6d062f1dee5e2)
- [Matching Unstructured Product Offers to Structured Product Descriptions - Microsoft Research](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/matching-unstructured-product-offers-to-structured-product-descriptions/)
- [Tailoring entity resolution for matching product offers](http://disi.unitn.it/~p2p/RelatedWork/Matching/Kopcke_edbt2012.pdf)